# How to set an exact size-text after the animation text?

Tags: html, css, web-animations

This is my first approach to html5/css3 animations.

I have a fadeIn and scale effect on text.

When animation is finished, I have a problem. The text is resized. 
I dont want this.

I wish that the text remains the same size at the end of the animation
`(30px)`.

[sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNPmjY)

Comment: Might be easier to also include the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your maximum font size to the .textEffect class

```
.textEffect
    {
        -webkit-animation-name:fadin;
        -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier( .83,.27,.55,1);
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        font-size:30px;
    }
```

[Example Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rORmbq)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But at what value " returned " to the end of the animation ? and why?

Comment: The text was returning to the default font-size set by the browser (16px).

This is because you hadn't overridden the font-size on the text you were animating.